# My Interceptor is Ignored and Authorization header is not set when I send a request

Tags: angular, jwt, http-headers

this the **auth.interceptor.ts**:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    
    

    const modifiedReq = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.authService.getToken()
      }
 })     
    return next.handle(modifiedReq);
  }
}
```

and this is **app.module.ts**:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    LayoutModule,
    HttpClientModule
  
  ],
  
  providers: [
    MessageService,
    ConfirmationService,
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true }
],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I want to use the Interceptor in my **book module** (lazy loaded module) which exists inside **Layout Module** (lazy loaded module) which exists inside my **app module**.
P.S: I have used **HttpClientModule **only inside **appModule** but it does not work !
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root',
 })
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const modifiedReq = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', this.authService.getToken())
 })     
    return next.handle(modifiedReq);
  }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work ! the interceptor still ignored... i don't know what is going on

Comment: Try some logs to assert the code is being really called. Also try provided in Root on injectabel decorator

Comment: I tried some logs and i figured out that interceptor works but the header doesn't set

Comment: when i write "console.log(req.headers);" the header authorization are set in log but in the request that i sent there is no header set (when i look it from 'Network')

Comment: after the code in my answer you should log the modifiedReq. If the this.authService.getToken() is not null or undifined you must have a header setted

Comment: I once had this problem, my mistake was that I was providing `HttpClientModule` in more than one place. Just provide it once

Comment: yes i provided it just in app.module.ts but with no result